# angularjs datepicker not loading current date

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker

I am trying to implement the angularjs datepicker. The datepicker loads but it will not load on the current date. it keeps loading to the oldest date in the datepicker which is 1st October 1935. As you can see but the code below I have added the current date to the  tag using ng-model. I have printed the variable I have passed into the  using ng-model and it prints the current date. Why is the datepicker not loading on the current date. I have checked everywhere and my code seems to be correct.

datepicker.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('dateSelector', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages'])
    .component('dateSelector', {
        templateUrl: '/static/js/angular/date-selector/src/date-selector.template.html',
        bindings:{
            dateSelectorVisible: '='
        },
        controller: ['$scope', function dateSelectorContoller($scope){
            var self = this;
            self.$onInit = function(){
                self.startDate = new Date();
                self.endDate = new Date();
            }
        }]
    });
```

date-selector.template.html

```
    <md-content  layout="column" layout-gt-sm="row" >
        <div layout="column" flex-order="1" flex-order-gt-sm="0">
            <md-subheader>Start Date {{$ctrl.startDate}}</md-subheader>
            <md-calendar ng-model="$ctrl.startDate"></md-calendar>
        </div>
        <div layout="column" flex-order="1" flex-order-gt-sm="1">
            <md-subheader>End Date</md-subheader>
            <md-calendar ng-model="$ctrl.endDate"> </md-calendar>
        </div>
    </md-content>
```

the angular controllers, directives and components are all loaded correctly the issue seems to just be with the datepicker code

Comment: Please create an [mcve] using https://codepen.io or https://stackblitz.com and share the link in your question (use the [edit] link below your question text to add the link).

Comment: I tried but I cant load a template with a angularjs component in codepen. The datepicker opens up on the correct date when i use it inside a controller but when I try use it inside template called by my component it doesnt load the correct date

Comment: I found the issue. The template was being loaded before the data was intialized